# TypeScript generics will only infer union types in simple cases

Tags: typescript

Here's a code example:

```
declare function test_ok<T>(arr: T[]): T;
test_ok([1, 2, "hello"]); // OK
test_ok([[1], [2], ["hello"]]); // OK

// note the nested array signature
declare function test_err<T>(arr: T[][]): T;
test_err([[1], [2], ["hello"]]); // ERR type "string" is not assignable to type "number"
test_err<string | number>([[1], [2], ["hello"]]); // OK if generic is specified
```

It seems that the general case, TypeScript is able to infer the best common type (a basic union) when given a heterogeneous array. However, if you try to scope the generic any further than just a simple array (such as the nested array above), it gives up. I've also found this with other cases (e.g. an array of functions where the generic is over the *return type* of the functions, rather than entire functions). Is this some sort of performance optimization?

Comment: This also happens for any property of depth two or more, not just arrays: `declare function x<T>(a: { x: {y: T}, u: {v: T}}): void; x({x: {y: 1}, u: {v: ""}});`

Comment: TypeScript does best at inferring a type given a value of that type, as opposed to inferring a type given a value of some *function* of that type.  So I'd try `declare function foo<T extends any[][]>(arr: T): T[number][number];` instead... does that match your use case?  Still not sure if there's an official answer for why the inference "gives up" at two layers deep.  Could be intentional, since sometimes you *want* things like this to fail.

Comment: Looks like this is probably intentional, see [related comment on microsoft/TypeScript#31617](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31617#issuecomment-496581018)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for both the workaround, as well as the link. I’ll approve it if you put it into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to say this is more like intentional error-catching and not a performance optimization.  When trying to infer `T` given a set of values that are supposed to be of type `T`, you can always succeed by widening `T` to fit all values, but then it's impossible to catch a legitimate mistake, where one of the values was entered incorrectly.  This is a judgment call by the designers of the language, I think, and likely any heuristic would produce some false positives and some false negatives.

The GitHub issue [microsoft/TypeScript#31617](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31617) is a similar report, where a user expects `string | number` to be inferred from two arguments, one of type `string` and the other of type `number`.  The [response](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31617#issuecomment-496581018) from one of the language maintainers is:

> This is an intentional trade-off so that generics can catch errors where you expect multiple objects to be of the same type, which is usually more common.

---

So, what can be done?  Obviously you can manually specify `T` as `string | number`.  Otherwise, if you want your function to be permissive and never throw an error, you can make `T` the type of the given argument itself.  The compiler is much more consistent about inferring a type given an value of that type than it is when given a value of some *function* of that type.  So my workaround here would be this for arrays:

```
declare function test_fixed<T extends any[][]>(arr: T): T[number][number];
const ret = test_fixed([[1], [2], ["hello"]]); // string | number
```

In this case, `T` is constrained to be a doubly-nested array, and the return type, `T[number][number]` is the element type of the innermost array (if you take `T`, and look up a value at a `number` index, you will get another array type... if you look up a value of *that* at a `number` index, you get the innermost element type... `T[number][number]`.)

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMB9HAawB4AVAPgApYYAueGgbQF0BKNmgNwBYAFCES5Cgw4BGADTwATAoBEACxAQIOFbwHwA9AfgB5ANKjxZStNlcFHRffgd1m7br2Hj50aNCQsAgo6Nh4BMRkiFgAHiDAtPAgMYSowETwUKgAntzcjMz8fOwcqMgAtgBGIDBcpRXVtcIiYHgk8HAY8AC8ERLRccC2Ms6Oo25aOlxeRvAkMFioAObwAD7wZVU1okA)