# Dynamic, variable or index based generic type variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to type a function that takes as input a variety of `classes` in the form of array elements or array of arrays consisting of a `class` and the name of its `method`. Something like that:

```js
fn([Class1, Class2, [Class3, 'method3'], ..., ClassN]);
```

I also want to rigidly indicate that if `[[class, method]]` pattern is selected, then it is possible to specify the method of only this particular class.

```js
type Class<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class A {
  a(): any {}
}

class B {
  b(): any {}
}

// ...

function fn<T>(arg: Array<
  Class<T> // <-- pick type of T dynamically??
  | [Class<T>, keyof T] // <-- pick type of T dynamically??
>): any {
  // do something with arg..
}

fn([
  A,        // ok
  [A, 'a'], // ok
  B,        // type error: Property 'a' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.
  [B, 'b'], // same type error..., expecting only "b" available here
]);
```

Is there some way for the type variable `T` to pick the type of the `class` on each iteration (array element)?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried and where you are seeing issues?

Comment: I was trying to come up with an indexed construct for `T`. Something like `T[I in keyof T]`, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Referencing this thread- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31617 and the following code-

```js
type Class<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class A {
  a(): any {}
}

class B {
  b(): any {}
}

type ArgType<T> = Class<T> | [Class<T>, keyof T]

type ArgDefinition<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ArgType<T[K]>[]
}

declare function fn<T>(arg: ArgDefinition<T>): void

fn({a: [
  A,
  [A, 'a'], // shows error
  B,
  [B, 'b'], // shows error
]})

type X = ArgType<A | B>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IDwBUB8UC8UB2EA7lABQB0lCATgOZIBcUC+IA2gLoCUu26A3AChBAY0QooAQSgBvQVAXNSXJixCyAvoK2jxSKACFZ8xQCNlq1pu3DQkKXXTgIGbHnjI0WKAB8obDxRXABooAGsIEAB7ADModA5bZwdaABEIGIBLfEzgTKj8V1xjRX8AaShs8MjY+I4mSUdnDDYyjkxOG0EAEwgxGmgYgFd8ETyCqBjCrFIaWga6dKyc8enMFSgANyjM7uEp0jlShCY2E1KFSWDzi7YrqAByBAeOa4vFAzf3-0-H0xevgpEhouEl7AANYqNWhOSCoaR+AzYAD0yKg1AgSCicE2EG6UDs0Ey+kCaARhmwfgCenhvgpoUIuOoHCAA)
The inferred type for property `a` in object in arguments in function `fn` is `ArgType<A | B>[]`. If you check type of `X`, it is `Class<A | B> | [Class<A | B>, never]`. That is, the keys have type `never` because intersection of `keyof A` and `keyof B` is `never`.

**It seems it is impossible to do such thing in Typescript as of now.**

Other links-

1. [TypeScript generics will only infer union types in simple cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57949235/11642727)
2. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31617#issuecomment-496867013

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, ensure the compiler your array will not be mutated, in other words, is a tuple. If you pass in an array literal, you will have to use const assertion (`as const`). As soon as you do that, you will see the type you defined is unsuitable for the task:

> The type 'readonly [typeof A, readonly [typeof A, "a"], typeof B, readonly [typeof B, "b"]]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '(Class | [Class, never])[]'

Note that `keyof T` is resolved to `never` because `keyof unknown` is `never`. Why? Because the signature accepts a mutable `Array`, while we pass a `ReadonlyArray`. This is easily fixed, but takes us to square one as `T` is inferred as the type of the first element of the tuple:

```js
function fn<T>(arg: ReadonlyArray<
  Class<T> // <-- pick type of T dynamically??
  | [Class<T>, keyof T] // <-- pick type of T dynamically??
>): any {
  // do something with arg..
}

fn([A] as const); //function fn<A>(arg: readonly (Class<A> | [Class<A>, "a"])[]): any
```

So, secondly, we have to stop the compiler from inferring `T`. How? The simplest way (assuming you do not care about the exact type of constructors passed in) is to stop passing through the instance type and be content with a non-generic `Ctor`:

```js
type Ctor = new (...args: any[]) => any;

function fn2<T extends readonly (Ctor | readonly [Ctor, string])[]>(arg: T): any {
  // do something with arg..
}

fn2([
  A,        // ok
  [A, 'a'], // ok
  B,        // ok
  [B, 'b'], // ok
] as const)
```

All is well now, but we lost the ability to constrain the second member of the tuple to `keyof` of the instance (this is why the only constraint is `string`). Because `T` is now inferred as a tuple with members correctly typed, we can wrap the `arg` type into a mapped type to correct the shortcoming.

Something like this should do (all we do is reconstrain the second member of the tuple to `keyof` with a help of an `InstanceType` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype)):

```js
type Constrained<T extends readonly (Ctor | readonly [Ctor, string])[]> = {
    [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends readonly any[] ? readonly [ T[P][0],  keyof InstanceType<T[P][0]> ] : T[P]
};
```

And voila, the resulting signature is strictly typed:

```js
fn2([
  A,        // ok
  [A, 'a'], // ok
  B,        // ok
  [B, 'b'], // ok
  [B, "missing"] // Type '"missing"' is not assignable to type 'keyof B'
] as const)

fn2([[A, "a"]]) //ok
fn2([[A, "unknown"]]) //Type '"unknown"' is not assignable to type '"a"'
```

Notice that we could even drop the `as const` assertion, but be careful: if you do that, the passed in tuple has to be homogenous, or the second member of the tuple will not be narrowed to a string literal:

```js
fn2([[A, "never"], B]) //ok as the inferred type is ([typeof A, string] | typeof B)[]
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IDwBUB8UC8UB2EA7lABQB0lCATgOZIBcUC+IA2gLoCUu26A3AFgAUCIDGiFFACCUAN4iozUlyYsQ8gL4jto4RORIoAIXmKoAIxVrWWgDTmx1ggFcAthYjUzwpX6jUEMAu1PhQAExCvlC6uiIA9PFQlOQiIgBmLvhiwACWAPZh6fgYmKQ0tEwAShAIACaFcCDS1NQIIKjm8IalUIlQqAC0g1BguWIA1lCgkFD56VDoUHUg+Ahu4whwTQD8O+YAPlBs3SildlATECDzixx9SUMjY5PT4NC3SytrG2Jbu-thJhVMxbApov0GlAkPk3EEABa5fC0KBEXLAeHMOiUHRpYQzaBhPBXG4LLITfD5Ij4fgPQgANy8eOKpDY5mkF38fn6+Qm5jYHKgAHIEEKOBceXzosZOVyHm9Zl5qPlqEwAArKyDUUDC0VQXJGDYoJEopEK6BC4xCywuYABCAARxcuUCdX1YQJwukQtS0TYMuFFjFEqSSHW0E9SpVKQuEAAHpAcia5vgmlAAEQWdPMekIXKICxwaDwrwQET3ZBQMSFJDALhRDL4VnSCtGav4Wv1h6ZbJ5QpQYqoaRlCpMQL1RoaUinNDDqBHE6SWeYC7phDp7icEHqPGemDAFW4AjEMgpCqMUHsbi8S8N-HvWA14BtJEQOoYKDx4AQfB1IzjhpUynfdDyOADJ2OEDqAuWtqBNTcOGwPBwX8Ng1XdS5rk+e4mHQND7i-H8-3tCcgMvTgoB2EjALTNhFnwtgAAZxSUElbgASQ7YAWDECB0HeDAGOY7AcPotUOB0O8eyTftinCD9CN-f9aho4CD28MCVIgk51Jg594K4TgRzoJgYCfF9CHfLBtzBcxIXyaFYQRZM0QxLFaBxYQ4mEOTWXZWUuUlflBRFYN5V5cwAzlcKpSUf0LiFIMWKCv0A3TI0kBNDd5X42YhXSg1MuRdNrQNAh8jtQxcloNZCwjBzPSFNiFitctmDbJ8uGZfBwlZAVV3XDhr0SCKfJ6vrBXTclKWpDceESXKLSm-AKSpfASv1IxKUq40aoQOrpgah98vXIVG16th+ozBkvA3C5jGG+J-jmKZKwxaAkXSJU33NTayDYAlbkFWD4Pnc1bmMQyOCAA)