# Generic function return union type of arguments in parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have this piece of code

```
const func = <T>(...args: T[]): T => {
    return args[0]
}

// Expected return type: string | number
func("string", 12345)
```

Right now when I try doing this I will get an error on the second parameter saying

```
Argument of type '12345' is not assignable to parameter of type '"string"'.
```

How do I allow this function to take in a string and number and let the return type of `func` be `string | number` depending on the data types in the parameters?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57949235/2887218), or at least my answer would be nearly identical.  There are many cases where people are happy that `foo<T>(x: T, y: Y): void` doesn't allow `foo(123, "xyz")`. My approach here would be [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WJRGRW), where you make the function generic in the args array type instead of the elements of the array.

Comment: You just need to declare the type in the function call. `func<string | number>("string", 12345)` I don't see the need to explicitly declare the expected generic type a problem, but rather a feature. If your function should always accept `string | number` I would directly type the `args` array such rather than using generics. (assigning `any[]` doesn't seem like a gain but a sidestep around the desired constraint)

Comment: well I need the return type to be dynamically generated based on the input parameters so I am unable to just declare `string | number` beside the function. Is there really no way to do this?

Comment: are there any bounds to the possible types? otherwise perhaps the `any[]` solution proposed by @jcalz is the thing for you.

Comment: @zS1L3NT "Is there really no way to do this?" Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57949235/2887218) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57949417/2887218)?  Your choices here are either call `func<string | number>("", 0)` or to rewrite `func` so that it is generic in the array type and not the array element type.  You can't tell the compiler "it's okay to infer `T` as `string | number`". See [ms/TS#31617](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31617) for the canonical issue.

Comment: I saw the link to the TypeScript playground code and that worked for me @jcalz. If you make that link an answer to this question I'll mark it as the correct answer